# Easiest way to compare two file lists in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a directory with files `frame*` (schema) and `input_frame*` (schema), where `frame` and `input_frame` are prefixes for two different types of files. If one takes just the characters after the prefixes and compares the two file lists, then the set of files `frame*` is always a subset of the set `input_frame*`.

I'd like to remove the files in `input_frame*` that don't have an equivalent member in `frame*`. Is there an easy way to do this in bash?

Comment: `comm -1 -2 <(ls frame*) <(ls input_frame* | sed 's/input_//g')`

Comment: Would you like to _delete_ those files, or merely filter them out of your result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
for f in input_frame*; do [[ ! -f "${f#input_}" ]] && echo rm "$f"; done
```

Once you're satisfied with the output remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (test it first by using `echo` instead of `rm`):

```
for i in input_frame*;
    if [ ! -e ${i/input_/} ]; then
        rm $i
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `frame` is itself a suffix of `input_frame`, you can accomplish this with a simple use of the `#` parameter expansion operator.

```
for f in input_frame*; do
    [[ -f "${f#input_}" ]] || rm "$f"
done
```

For example, if `f` is `input_frame97`, then `${f#input_}` expands to `frame97`. Just check if the modified file name exists, and if not, remove the original.